# GCP Datastore gray/unsearchable entities?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, datastore

I have a datastore with the following schema:

[image]

Typically, we want to search for an `obfuscated_session_id` and return it's corresponding `session_id`.  These are always 1-to-1 and never empty.  For example:

[image]

The filter is always a simple equality.

I recently noticed that sometimes our searches return nothing even though there's definitely a result.  For the few records that this occurs, datastore grays out the column header as shown below.  **What does this grayed out header mean?**

[image]

PS - this store has NO custom indexes of any sort.

### ----Update----

It looks like the issue is related to the fact that some code that uploaded these specified that certain columns are indexed.

```
class ObfuscatedVideo(Schema):
    obfuscated_video_id = StringProperty(required=True, indexed=True)
    video_id = StringProperty(required=True)
    obfuscated_session_id = StringProperty(required=True)
    session_id = StringProperty(required=True, indexed=True)
```

Where Schema is a custom library class used to wrap some GCP functions.  Seems like that most of our uploads work, but the gray index corresponds to the fields above that are not explicitly marked as `indexed=True`.  Could be an issue on our end, hard to say, but it's most certainly due to this.

Comment: Is your choice to use / in your obfuscated session? The grey title is strange. What is your database throughput?

Comment: Not sure of specifics, but throughput is low (maybe a few dozen writes/reads a day).  The `/` is not used in the `obfuscated_session_id`.  Furthermore, it's only a few entrie that are grayed.  I didnt show, but the vast majority of results in table are not grayed out.

Comment: What's your problem? When you search a obfuscated session id, it return no result when the header is in Grey?

Comment: Correct that's it

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere is this something I should fill out a GCP support ticket for?

Comment: I tried to reproduce and to find somewhere what means this grey header, and I'm not succeeded. I recommend you to fill a ticket. And, if you can, post a comment here to let us know what is the true reason and how you fixed it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I updated the thread - wondering if that made anything more obvious.  Looks related to this usage of `indexed=True`, but could be on our end since we're wrapping the GCP client in a `Schema` class